# Click goes through element when there is an overlay - how does it work?

Tags: html, css, dom, input, upload

I have found the technique to customize file input element through putting a regular button in "front of it" and make the file input element with `opacity: 0`. Like this:

```
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#button-on-top {
   width: 200px;
   padding: 10px;
}

#file-input-below {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 200px;
   padding: 10px;
}
```

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <button id="button-on-top">Upload</button>
   <input type="file" id="file-input-below">
</div>
```

But why does it actually work that when you click the button "above", the click goes to the real file input button and activates it? Normally, when there's an element "below" another, it doesn't register a click.

Such as with different kinds of overlays where buttons underneath cannot be clicked?

Thank you for an explanation in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML files are rendered from top to bottom, so your input field is rendered later. That means if you put absolute to your button the input field slides under it.

But if you put your button below your button will slide under your input field.

If you still want to make it work put to your button an index-z of 1

```
   #button-on-top {
    z-index: 1;
     }
```

and your input field should have an lower z-index then your button if you want to make your button clickable

```
  #file-input-below {
  z-index: -1;
}
```